# household_objects_database returns 3: query error

Tags: ros, household-objects-database

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

after launching the remote client to the household objects database with

$ roslaunch household_objects_database objects_database_remote_client.launch

(which correctly remaps the services), queries to the database always return a result code 3 DATABASE_QUERY_ERROR, e.g. for the following queries on both cturtle and diamondback.

$ rosservice call /objects_database_node/get_model_list REDUCED_MODEL_SET

$ rosservice call /objects_database_node/get_model_mesh 18800

Has the service definition changed, or is the server down?

best,
Moritz

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9245/household_objects_database-returns-3:-query-error/) by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2673 on 2011-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

the problem occurred when using the database hosted at Willow Garage, and got solved by Matei who re-started their server :)

Thanks anyway,
Moritz

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2011-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-02**:
ok :) glad to hear you solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Moritz,

Did you follow these tutorials?

http://www.ros.org/wiki/sql_database/Tutorials/Installing%20a%20PostgreSQL%20Server

and

http://www.ros.org/wiki/household_objects_database/Tutorials/Install%20the%20household_objects%20database%20on%20your%20local%20database%20server

You should make sure that you can log in your database and that it is not empty using pgadmin3 on the computer where the database is installed.

Please, make sure that your *my_server.yaml* file contains the correct login information and that your launch file (objects_database_remote_client.launch) uses it.

You can make sure of the service definition by using rosservice:

```
$rosservice list
$rosservice type [SERVICE_NAME]
$rosservice info [SERVICE_NAME]
```

If it does not help, please send your launch file, yaml file, and a screenshot of your rxgraph.

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1